# How to secure an authentication in swift

Tags: php, ios, swift, security, encryption

I'm quite new to programming apps for iOS. I've had a deeper look into creating a login for an app. The procedure is quite clear to me but I have couple of concerns regarding the security aspect.

A) The app is sending the credentials that were provided by the user to an API that can be written in php. This API is then going to verify the credentials and sending a response back to the app. However isn't this a big security issue? Isn't it possible to verify some credentials for everyone who has the adress of the API?

B) Secondly I haven't seen a tutorial that properly encrypts the credentials in the app before sending them to the api. If they do an encryption they let the API do the job. What would be a proper way to encrypt them in the app and send the encrypted credentials to the API? Would I need to store a secret key in my app?

I'm asking this because I would like to do it the proper way right from the beginning. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would start by saying make sure that your server has `SSL` and `ipv6` functionality ready. (Taking care of these right of the bat, prevents your app from being rejected when it goes to App Review)

In term of securing your api routes, you could look into `JWT token`. JWT works with passphrase or certificate (meaning private and public keys, think about when you want to ssh to a server without password).

> I'd preferred to use certificates, however you need to make sure that you don't lose these certificates, because once your app is ready for sale only these specific certificates would allow your app to talk to that api.

Once all routes of your api are secured, I'd:

- generate & store a default token into your app's keychain (its purpose is to only allow you to access your api once)
- From api side, create a route `(/generate_token)` that will read that default token, and if valid you generate a new token and send it as response.
- delete that default token from the keychain and store that new token there.

When your iOS app first launched, you could have some kind of `isAlreadyFetchedToken = false` variable saved into your UserDefault. This variable allow you to track if you have a new token or not.

```
if isAlreadyFetchedToken == false {
    // load the default token into some variable 
    let default_token = ...
   // create custom http header 
   let header = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(default_token)" ]
   // access your /generate_token route from your api 
    // if you get a response it should contain a new_token 
    // save new token into keychain && remove default one 
  // update userDefault var to true 
     isAlreadyFetchedToken = true 
}
```

Now every time you want to access your api, you'd load that token from the keychain, and pass it into your api routes' `Authorization header` for example `[Authorization: "Bearer" + new_token]`.

> This is one way, and not the only way

Answer (score 0):

An API **should** allow requests from anyone and anywhere.  If your API allows requests from anywhere and is **still** secure, then it is well designed.  If your API is only secure when communicating with specific client software, then your API is poorly designed.

The solution is simple.  Use TLS, and implement a decent authentication system.  JWT tokens are a good start.